# Paypal PhP api security issue

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I was trying to use the express checkout php api. Everything is working well in the sandbox environment. My question is regarding security.

After payment the sample code redirects to GetExpressCheckout.php?token=...$PayerID=.....; But after clicking "confirm payment" in my site and logging in to paypal account (did not confirm payment in paypal);  I directly opened the same page in another tab, and it showed payment successful (which is not the case). Is there a way to prevent this or am I missing some thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not following exactly what you're trying to say here.

The process needs to be...

1) Call SetExpressCheckout to retrieve your token and redirect to PayPal accordingly.

2) PayPal will return the user back to your ReturnURL if they confirm payment, at which point you can call GetExpressCheckoutDetails (optionally) and DoExpressCheckoutPayment to finalize the payment.

Not until DECP is completed does any transaction actually take place.  The success message you're seeing probably came from GetExpressCheckoutDetails, which does nothing more than retrieve the buyer/order info so that you can finalize the payment on your site.

Comment: Thank you. I was confused with GECD details.